# What happens when you get disconnected from a database during a transaction?

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, orm

I was connected via ssh to a remote Postgres DB.
I was deleting all the rows of a table using SQLAlchemy

```py
db_session.query(TableName).delete()
```

but before the deletion was completed I got disconnected from the internet.

Now `delete` seems broken.
All the rows are still there, and I can query them, but when I run the above command it begins an endless waiting.

Maybe the db is still waiting for the previous transaction to terminate?
What can I do?

I hope someone can help me. Thank you.

Comment: Check pg_stat_activity to see what the current state is of your database, what it is doing, what tables/records are locked, etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot @FrankHeikens ! Actually while a was searching for more details about `pg_stat_activity` the deletion terminated, and the next ones lasted a regular amount of time, but `pg_stat_activity` will be very useful anyway